# OVER PARTITION BY giving error in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have following query:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    SUM(BalanceQty) OVER (PARTITION BY Item_Code ORDER BY [Date])
FROM 
    (SELECT
         Date, Item_Code, 
         SUM(In_Quantity) AS In_Quantity, 
         SUM(Issue_Quantity) AS Issue_Quantity, 
         (SUM(In_Quantity) - SUM(issue_Quantity)) AS BalanceQty    
     FROM
         (SELECT
              tbl_add_product.Date as Date, 
              tbl_add_product.Item_Code, 
              tbl_add_product.In_Quantity, 
              0 as Issue_Quantity 
          FROM 
              tbl_add_product
          WHERE
              Item_Code = 'pen' 

          UNION ALL

          SELECT 
              tbl_issue_product.Date as Date, 
              tbl_issue_product.Item_Code, 
              0 as In_Quantity, 
              Issue_Quantity 
          FROM
              tbl_issue_product
          WHERE
              Item_Code = 'pen') X 
    GROUP BY 
        Item_Code, Date) o
```

It is working fine in SQL Server 2012 but it is causing an error in SQL server 2008. Please suggest solution to it.

Comment: `Partition By` is supported but `order by` is unsupported inside `over()` in sql server 2008.

Comment: what is solution to it ?

Comment: Solution: use 2012 - you already said that it works

Comment: Although a solution has been mentioned, including the actual error message might help future searches.

Comment: *What* error does it cause in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want a solution which can work on both then try this :

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Date,
                Item_Code,
                Sum(In_Quantity)                           AS In_Quantity,
                Sum(Issue_Quantity)                        AS Issue_Quantity,
                ( Sum(In_Quantity) - Sum(issue_Quantity) ) AS BalanceQty
         FROM   (SELECT tbl_add_product.Date AS Date,
                        tbl_add_product.Item_Code,
                        tbl_add_product.In_Quantity,
                        0                    AS Issue_Quantity
                 FROM   tbl_add_product
                 WHERE  Item_Code = 'pen'
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT tbl_issue_product.Date AS Date,
                        tbl_issue_product.Item_Code,
                        0                      AS In_Quantity,
                        Issue_Quantity
                 FROM   tbl_issue_product
                 WHERE  Item_Code = 'pen') X
         GROUP  BY Item_Code,Date)
SELECT *,(select SUM(BalanceQty) from cte c2 where c2.Date <=c1.Date)
FROM   cte c1
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the database compatibility mode in SQL SERVER 2008, Right click on database select properties, click on "Options" change "Compatibility Level:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure but it won't show `sql server 2012` in that combo if it is sql server 2008 smss.

Comment: what is the currently selected value under 2008

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `outer apply` or a correlated subquery:

```
with t as (<your big subquery here>)
select t.*
       (select sum(BalanceQty)
        from t t2
        where t2.Item_Code = t.Item_Code and t2.[Date] <= t.[Date]
       ) as RunningBalance
from t;
```

EDIT:

You can add the `Item_Code = 'pen'` to the outer query, if you want to limit the results to one item.

Comment: you can remove Item code condition as all the rows will have same item code as per given query.